# How to use multiple streams and .map functions in java 8 with lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List counties` which contains unique county names only, and a `List txcArray` which contains a city name, county name and population for that city.

I need to get the largest city name of each county from `txcArray` using only Java 8 with lambda expressions and `Stream`s.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
List<String> largest_city_name = 
    counties.stream() 
            .map(a -> txcArray.stream()
                              .filter(b ->  b.getCounty().equals(a))
                              .mapToInt(c -> c.getPopulation())
                              .max())
            .collect( Collectors.toList());
```

I am trying to add another .map statement after `.max()` to get the name of the `City` with the largest population but my new lambda expression does not exists from the stream of txcArray it only recognizes it as an `int` type and a texasCitiesClass type. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
 List<String> largest_city_name = 
     counties.stream() 
             .map(a -> txcArray.stream()
                               .filter( b ->  b.getCounty().equals(a))
                               .mapToInt(c->c.getPopulation())
                               .max()
                               .map(d->d.getName()))
             .collect( Collectors.toList());
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `counties` list altogether. Just stream `txcArray` and group by county:

```
Collection<String> largestCityNames = txcArray.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                City::getCounty,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.maxBy(City::getPopulation),
                        o -> o.get().getName())))
        .values();
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about that. Much simpler. +1

Comment: I suppose, the original intention was that the list of largest city names is in the same order is the list of counties. Here, it might be better to keep the `Map` rather than an unordered collection of city names…

Answer (score 3):

Well, once to `map` the `Stream` of cities into an `IntStream`, there's no way for you to recover the name of the city corresponding with the `int` value.

Use `Stream`'s `max` instead of converting to `IntStream`:

```
List<String> largest_city_name =
    counties.stream() 
            .map(a -> txcArray.stream()
                              .filter(b ->  b.getCounty().equals(a))
                              .max(Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation))
                              .get())
            .map(City::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way the `map` operation maps each county to its `City` with the highest population. Note that `max` returns an `Optional<City>`, so it the `Optional` is empty (i.e. some county has no cities), `get()` will throw an exception.

To avoid that issue, you can write:

```
List<String> largest_city_name =
    counties.stream() 
            .map(a -> txcArray.stream()
                              .filter(b ->  b.getCounty().equals(a))
                              .max(Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation))
                              .map(City::getName)
                              .orElse(""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will map a county having no cities into an empty `String`.

This code assumes `txcArray` is a `List<City>`, where `City` is:

class City {
       public String getName () {return nam;}
       public int getPopulation() {return pop;}
       public String getCounty() {return cnt;}
       String nam;
       int pop;
       String cnt;
       public City(String nam,int pop,String cnt) {
           this.nam = nam;
           this.pop = pop;
           this.cnt = cnt;
       }
   }

and `counties` is a `List<String>`. If my assumptions are not accurate, you'll have to make some adjustments.

Now, testing the code with the following `List`s:

```
List<String> counties=new ArrayList<> ();
counties.add ("First");
counties.add ("Second");
counties.add ("Third");
counties.add ("Fourth");
List<City> txcArray = new ArrayList<> ();
txcArray.add (new City("One",15000,"First"));
txcArray.add (new City("Two",12000,"First"));
txcArray.add (new City("Three",150000,"Second"));
txcArray.add (new City("Four",14000,"Second"));
txcArray.add (new City("Five",615000,"Third"));
txcArray.add (new City("Six",25000,"Third"));
```

produces this output `List`:

```
[One, Three, Five, ]
```

Comment: You are right I had the wrong variable name thank you for helping me through it.